# Popover view controller crashes on iPad

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to display a view controller as pop over, it works fine on the iPhone when it's displayed full screen, but crashes on the iPad.

```
@IBAction func selectOpponentItems(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let VC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ItemSelectionVC") as! ItemSelectionVC
    // Error here
    VC.delegate = self
    VC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2)
    VC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
    self.present(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}
```

The error message says:

> Could not cast value of type
>   'UIViewController' (0x1b1e33f60) to 'Overpower.ItemSelectionVC'
>   (0x10005ad40).

Comment: What is the exception message?  Which line does it occur on?

Comment: @Paulw11 plz see the edit

Comment: Your force downcast is failing because it isn't an `ItemSelectionVC`, but simply a `UIViewController` - check your storyboard.

Comment: Yeah you are right, there's a mistake in my storyboard, but now it still crashes, says: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'UIPopoverPresentationController (<UIPopoverPresentationController: 0x12de06610>) should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs.'`

Comment: Does it mean I must embed it in a navigation VC?

Comment: No, it means you need to set the source for the popoverpresentationcontroller - what do you want it to "pop" from?

Comment: @Paulw11 from a button of this view controller

Comment: Yes, but you need to tell the popover this. You can either set it as a property of your popover segue or you can get a reference to the popoverpresebtationcontroller in prepareforsegue and set the source view there

Comment: @Paulw11 can you show me how to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39972979/popover-in-swift-3-on-iphone-ios/39975346#39975346

Comment: @TonyMkenu I think I have this in my code, plz read the question again

Comment: You are missing something in your code `sourceRect`, `sourceView`… check again the link

Comment: @TonyMkenu I see, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following @TonyMkenu's answer, I added these 2 lines of code to `selectOpponentItems`, and it worked like magic:

```
VC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
VC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.bounds
```