# Popover in swift 3 on iphone ios

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, popover

I am trying to make a popover menu with the following code:

```
import UIKit

class BeobachtungViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {


    @IBAction func addClicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        // get a reference to the view controller for the popover
        let popController = UIStoryboard(name: "Personenakte", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popoverId")

        // set the presentation style
        popController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover

        // set up the popover presentation controller
        popController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.up
        popController.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
        popController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender as! UIView // button
        popController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.bounds

        // present the popover
        self.present(popController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method
    func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        // Force popover style
        return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
    }
}
```

This is working on iPad, but, on an iPhone, the popup takes the whole iPhone screen. I just want a small window with an arrow. I found several tutorials but none worked for me.

Comment: as far as i know, that is the intended behaviour by apple, there are no popups on iphone

Comment: your code it's working for me.... but your delegate it's not correct

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Change your delegate method to:

```
func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    // return UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
}
```

Comment: @TonyMkenu Not working in iPhone, please let me know how does it work?

Comment: What if you only want one of the controller to be popover not all? I have a situation that I only want one of the controllers to be popover.

Comment: @LimThyeChean The delegate method hands you the controller. You could guard for that one (because you've kept a reference to it) and return accordingly.

Comment: It seems like this does not work with a TableViewController as Popover