# Swift 3 - adaptivePresentationStyle is never called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, popover

I am trying to show a popover in an iPhone. I am following the suggestions that i found here and using the delegate "adaptivePresentationStyle", but this function is never called and the ViewController it will always presented in fullscreen mode. I have the "UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate" and the functions bellow:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        let identifier  = segue.destination.restorationIdentifier ?? ""
        if identifier == "NavigationSetup" {
            if let destinationNav   = segue.destination as? UINavigationController {
                let destination  = destinationNav.topViewController as! SetupTableViewController
                destination.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
                destination.popoverPresentationController?.backgroundColor  = UIColor.blue
                if self.myApp.isIpad{
                    destination.preferredContentSize  = CGSize(width: 600, height: 620)
                }else{
                    destination.preferredContentSize  = CGSize(width: 0.8 * self.view.frame.size.width, height: 0.8 * self.view.frame.size.height)
                }

                self.cellAnimations.fade(image: self.imageBlur, initOpacity: 0, endOpacity: 1, time: 0.3, completion: nil)
                destination.setupDismiss = {[weak self] () in
                    if let weakSelf = self{
                        weakSelf.cellAnimations.fade(image: weakSelf.imageBlur, initOpacity: 1, endOpacity: 0, time: 0.3, completion: nil)
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
    func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller:UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        print("adaptive was called")
        return .none
    }
```

So, what i am missing here ?

Comment: I think.. you are missing.. `popController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover`

Comment: check this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39972979/popover-in-swift-3-on-iphone-ios/39975346#39975346

Comment: Thanks man, but i was using the "destination" and should be using the "destinationNav". It´s working now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, set a breakpoint to make sure this line is being called:

```
destination.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
```

Even better, rewrite like this, and set a breakpoint to make sure the inner line is being called:

```
if let pop = destination.popoverPresentationController {
    pop.delegate = self
}
```

If it is, good! In that case the problem is probably that implementing the wrong delegate method. You want this:

```
func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, 
    traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
```

Comment: Thank ´s man, you are right , i should be using the "destinationNav" and not the "destination".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you did not present it well

```
let vc = UIViewController()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .custom;
vc.transitioningDelegate = self;
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Presenting with custom Modal presentation and making it animated while presenting should do the trick