# Popup displays as fullscreen

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, popup, segue

I want to display a view controller inside a view controller. I'm using popup segue to do this. Second view controllers settings are like below and but It shows in fullscreen anyway.

```
 func tappedView3() {
    // get a reference to the view controller for the popover
    let popController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popoverId")

    // set the presentation style
    popController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover

    // set up the popover presentation controller
    popController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.up
    popController.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
    popController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = m_tumgun // button
    popController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = m_tumgun.bounds

    // present the popover
    self.present(popController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method
func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    // Force popover style
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
}
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39975346/1702413

Answer (score 0):

You should use **Container View** for this.

[image]

[image]

Read more here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

Comment: I red about containerview but my problem is that I'm opening second view via a button and that button disappears when new container view opened. As I searched, for example that button should be still in view.

Comment: @EmreÖnder, Container View is just view. You can add it as a subview of your main view controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
class TablePopupController: UIViewController {
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    self.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    self.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
/// to touch button which pressed
///
/// - Parameter sender: button presse
@IBAction func toDismissView(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.handler!(nil)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

you can use it in other controller by following line

```
let lifeStyleTablePopup = TablePopupController(nibName: NibName.TablePopupController.rawValue, bundle: nil)
self.present(self.lifeStyleTablePopup, animated: true, completion: {
})
```

I hope this will helps you